# qtcreator qimage value changing

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, opencv

I am trying to make a QTCreator video streaming application, and I want it to display current frames at the FPS I want, while keeping on getting new frames at the same time, and have the ability to view previous frames and next frames as well, much like a forward and reverse button in a video player.
For this purpose, I am converting the `cv::Mat` object received from a `VideoCapture` object into a `QImage` using a class `Player`.

`Player` object keeps generating the QImages as fast as possible:

```
cv::cvtColor(frame, RGBframe, CV_BGR2RGB);
img = QImage((const unsigned char*)(RGBframe.data),
             RGBframe.cols,RGBframe.rows,RGBframe.step,QImage::Format_RGB888);
```

After this, `Player` emits a signal:

```
emit originalImage(img);
```

This signal is connected in MainWindow as:

```
connect(player, SIGNAL(originalImage(QImage)), this, 
                         SLOT(updateDisplay(QImage)));
```

From `updateDisplay`, I push the `QImage` into a `QVector<QImage>` vector which is acting as a buffer, in a separate class `Display` which I use to handle the frames as I want:

```
void MainWindow::updateDisplay(QImage img){
    if(!img.isNull)
         display->push(img)
}
```

In `Display` class:

```
void Display::push(QImage image){
    mutex.lock();
    buffer.push_back(image);
    mutex.unlock();
}
```

Both `Display` and `Player` are threads. In `Display::run()`, I am trying to update a `QLabel` in `MainWindow` with frames at the speed I want. The problem is, in my `buffer` object, the previous values are changing when I push new values. In the run method, I tried doing the following in a loop:

```
if(!buffer.isEmpty()){
        QImage curr = buffer.at(0);
        label->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
        label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(curr).scaled(label->size(),
                                           Qt::KeepAspectRatio, Qt::FastTransformation));
        msleep(100);
    }
```

The `msleep` is for displaying the images at 10 FPS. This should keep updating the label with the same `QImage`, that is the one first pushed into `buffer`, but here lies my problem. When I test this, the label keeps changing and showing the latest image pushed into the buffer, even though it should show a static image.

Comment: You don't seem to be locking `mutex` in your loop; if you are accessing `buffer` from different threads this is going to cause trouble (although it may be not needed in general, depending on how you created player and main window they may be connected through a queued connection, in that case it's not needed even in `push`). Incidentally, I wouldn't use `QVector`, but `std::deque`, which doesn't need to reallocate when pushing/popping at the extremes.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Your `deque` tip proved very helpful, thanks! I didn't solve this problem, but somehow found a workaround.